# Splashscreen issue with full height display

Tags: android, xamarin, splash-screen

I am having an issue with viewing my splashscreen as per the design.It shows an incomplete vertical view but a complete horizontal view.
Here is the splashscreen design:

[image]

Here is what I get as display when added to my project:

[image]

I am using two images as bitmap and combining them.
Below is my splashscreen.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_splash_screen_bg_xx"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I tried setting android:gravity value in my splashscreen.xml to:
`android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"` yet I still get same incomplete vertical display

Comment: You can use scaleType property from ImageView and select appropriate value as required.

Comment: You should use the official splash screen APIs https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Comment: Did you try to use the `android:gravity="center"`? And there were two pictures and a text view in your splash, how did you deal with them?

Comment: I tried with the android:gravity="center" but it doesn't fix that.

Comment: If the bitmap contains two images, maybe you can try to set the bitmap. It seems the height of the bitmap is too big.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SplashScreenAPI introduce in android 12.